# Find Friends Numbers between an Interval

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find every couple of friends numbers between an interval. Between 110 and 210 i have to check
every possibility (110,210)(111,210)(112,210)......

Two numbers are friends if the sum of the divisor of the first is equal to the second number and viceversa.

I dont know why but the output none, the code asks for the numbers but then nothing happens. The expected output is every couple of numbers between the interval introduced that happens to be friends Can anyone help me?

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int suma = 0, suma1 = 0;
   
    int n, m;
    cout << "Number: \n";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Another number: \n";
    cin >> m;

    for(int i = n; i<m; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<=m; j++){
            suma = 0;
            suma1 = 0;
            for(int z = 1; z <= i/2; z++){
                if(i%z==0){
                suma = suma + i;
                 }
            }
                 
                

            for(int x = 1; x <= j/2; x++){
                if(j%x==0){
                suma1 = suma1 + x;
                 }
            }

            if(suma1==i && suma==j){

                cout << n << " y " << m << " they are friends";
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What is a happy number?

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work" means? What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: At least here: `if(i%z==0){`, I guess it should be `if(z%i==0){`. Moreover, your algorithm seems rather inefficient

Comment: No need to check 110 with every numbers, the only candidate is the sum of its divisors.

Comment: Here: `cout << n << " y " << m <<...`, you should output `i` and `j` instead

Comment: Create sub function to compute sum of divisors (and check it manually with small numbers).

Answer (score 1):

It is very well possible that your code is correct: the smallest pair of amical numbers is 220 and 284 (so below 210 you won't find anything).

Next to that, there are some other remarks to be made:
I advise you to write a separate function to calculate the sum of the divisors of a number, something like:

```
int sum_of_divivors(int input){
  int temp_sum = 0;
  for(int x = 1; x <= input/2; x++){ // don't go up to the number itself, 
                                     // the number itself should not be added 
                                     // in this sum.
    if(input%x==0){
      temp_sum += x;
    }
  }
  return temp_sum;
}
```

Then, do some debugging: show the evolution of variables on screen (using `cout`, `printf()` or whatever) or use a debugger.

Last but not least, add some comments in your code: why do you go from and to certain values in your for-loops, what are you implementing, ...